# MIPS Assembly language, how to save size of table to a register?

Tags: loops, assembly, mips

I am making a program that looks through a table of IP addresses to see if the IP address the user enters matches any that are in the table.  My professor is using a table that is of an unknown size.  I am currently using a counter that ++ every iteration through the loop that checks if the IP's match, but it only works when there are 10 entries because that is how I set it up.

```
IP_ROUTING_TABLE_SIZE:
.word 10
IP_ROUTING_TABLE:
# line #, x.x.x.x -------------------------------------
.word 0, 146, 163, 255, 255     # 146.163.255.255
.word 1, 147, 163, 255, 255     # 147.163.255.255 
.word 2, 201, 88, 88, 90        # 201.88.88.90
.word 3, 182, 151, 44, 56       # 182.151.44.56
.word 4, 24, 125, 100, 100      # 24.125.100.100
.word 5, 146, 163, 140, 80      # 146.163.170.80
.word 6, 146, 163, 147, 80      # 146.163.147.80
.word 7, 146, 164, 147, 80      # 146.164.147.80
.word 8, 148, 163, 170, 80      # 148.146.170.80
.word 9, 193, 77, 77, 10        # 193.77.77.10

.text
.globl main



main:

la $t5, IP_ROUTING_TABLE_SIZE


PROMPT:

li $t6, 0

li $v0, 4
la $a0, ENTER_PROMPT
syscall 

FIRST_ENTER:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, FIRST
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t1, $v0

blt $t1, 0, ERROR_FIRST_L
bgt $t1, 255, ERROR_FIRST_G

j SECOND_ENTER

    ERROR_FIRST_G:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_LARGE
        syscall

        j FIRST_ENTER

    ERROR_FIRST_L:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_SMALL
        syscall

        j FIRST_ENTER

SECOND_ENTER:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, SECOND
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t2, $v0

blt $t2, 0, ERROR_SECOND_L
bgt $t2, 255, ERROR_SECOND_G

j THIRD_ENTER

    ERROR_SECOND_G:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_LARGE
        syscall

        j SECOND_ENTER

    ERROR_SECOND_L:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_SMALL
        syscall

        j SECOND_ENTER

THIRD_ENTER:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, THIRD
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t3, $v0

blt $t3, 0, ERROR_THIRD_L
bgt $t3, 255, ERROR_THIRD_G

j FOURTH_ENTER

    ERROR_THIRD_G:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_LARGE
        syscall

        j THIRD_ENTER

    ERROR_THIRD_L:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_SMALL
        syscall

        j THIRD_ENTER

FOURTH_ENTER:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, FOURTH
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t4, $v0

blt $t4, 0, ERROR_FOURTH_L
bgt $t4, 255, ERROR_FOURTH_G

j IP_ADDRESS

    ERROR_FOURTH_G:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_LARGE
        syscall

        j FOURTH_ENTER

    ERROR_FOURTH_L:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, ERROR_SMALL
        syscall

        j FOURTH_ENTER


IP_ADDRESS:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, IP_IS
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t1
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, DOT
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t2
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, DOT
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t3
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, DOT
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t4
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, RETURN
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, RETURN
syscall

IP_CLASS:
bgt $t1, 0, CLASSA

    CLASSA:
        bgt $t1, 127, CLASSB

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, CLASS_A
        syscall

        j END

        CLASSB:
            bgt, $t1, 191, CLASSC

            li $v0, 4
            la $a0, CLASS_B
            syscall

            j END

            CLASSC:
                bgt, $t1, 223, CLASSD

                li $v0, 4
                la $a0, CLASS_C
                syscall

                j END
                CLASSD:
                    bgt, $t1, 239, CLASSE

                    li $v0, 4
                    la $a0, CLASS_D
                    syscall

                    j END
                    CLASSE:
                        li $v0, 4
                        la $a0, CLASS_E
                        syscall

END:
la $s0, IP_ROUTING_TABLE
CHECKPHASE:


lw $s1, 4($s0)
lw $s2, 8($s0)
lw $s3, 12($s0)
lw $s4, 16($s0)

bgt $s1, 0, MORETHAN1
    MORETHAN1:
        bgt $s1, 127, MORETHAN127

        beq $s1, $t1, MATCH_FOUND
        j END_CHECK

        MORETHAN127:
            bgt $s1, 191, MORETHAN191

            beq $s1, $t1, CHECK_1
            j END_CHECK
                CHECK_1:
                    beq $s2, $t2, MATCH_FOUND

            j END_CHECK

            MORETHAN191:
                bgt $s1, 223, ERRORNOTFOUND

                beq $s1, $t1, CHECK_1_2
                j END_CHECK
                    CHECK_1_2:
                        beq $s2, $t2, CHECK_2_2
                        j END_CHECK
                            CHECK_2_2:
                                beq $s3, $t3, MATCH_FOUND
                                j END_CHECK
```

This is where I need help.  How do I determine when the table has no more entries and it should jump to ERRORNOTFOUND?

```
END_CHECK:
add $t6, $t6, 1
beq $t6, $t5, ERRORNOTFOUND

addi $s0, $s0, 20


j CHECKPHASE

MATCH_FOUND:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, MATCH_FOUND_PRINT
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t6
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, RETURN
syscall

j END_OF_PROGRAM

ERRORNOTFOUND:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, ERROR_NOT_FOUND
syscall
j END_OF_PROGRAM

END_OF_PROGRAM:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, PROGRAM_COMPLETE
syscall

jr $31
syscall
```

Comment: *My professor is using a table that is of an unknown size.*  But the table is still a compile-time constant right?  Put a label at the end of the table, or `.equ table_len,  . - IP_ROUTING_TABLE` define an assemble-time constant.  (Not stored in memory: use it as an immediate).

Answer (score 1):

You are already checking if there are more entries in the table:

```
END_CHECK:
add $t6, $t6, 1
beq $t6, $t5, ERRORNOTFOUND
```

The t5 register is supposed to have the size of the table, but you put the whole word in there.  If you load the value to a different register, you can branch at the end of the table:

```
la $t5, IP_ROUTING_TABLE_SIZE
lw $t7, 0($t5)
```

Then, just change up your END_CHECK and it should work

```
END_CHECK:
add $t6, $t6, 1
beq $t6, $t7, ERRORNOTFOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to extend your table with terminator record, like:

```
.word 9, 193, 77, 77, 10        # 193.77.77.10
.word -1, 0, 0, 0, 0        # Terminator record
```

(if you can't use -1 in first word, you may still consider using something like `256` for first IP byte, as you define `.word` instead of `.byte`.

BTW, *WHY*? Each IPv4 address fits in single word (four bytes), why do you waste your RAM by defining them *4 longer?

That's disgusting misunderstanding of IPv4 design, it was designed in 1981 to fit into 32bit, because 4 billions of individual device addresses will be enough for every mainframe computer ever produced ... meanwhile some smartass started to sell home computer and ~decade later somebody got idea of connecting them to big network ... and ruined everything. So then IPv6 was designed, this time properly ... so much, that almost nobody wanted to implement it as first in device, that's why the migration to IPv6 is still in infancy.)

Then in the code:

```
    la $s0, IP_ROUTING_TABLE
CHECKPHASE:

    # load the first word in table (line number?)
    lw $s1, 0($s0)
    # check with -1?
    # Nah, generally for negative number should be OK, as you
    # will run out of memory before reaching line 0x80000000
    bltz $s1, ERRORNOTFOUND

    # continue with original code
    lw $s1, 4($s0)
```

From your question it's not clear how your prof will provide the variable length table (whether you can add the terminator record .. then again, Arnold Schwarzenegger approves it, so your professor can hardly resist)